# Django-single user with multiple employee account for each organization flow

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Im creating an application where user is having multiple employee account with each organization. When i login with user credential it has redirect to choose organization page which has multiple organisations where i hold employee accounts and after choosing any one organization it has to redirect to dashboard page where all details related to the selected organization should be displayed. My doubt is when im doing multiple  api calls in dashboard page whether i need to pass selected organization id in all requests?
ex: organization/orgid/team/teamid/members/team-member-id if this goes like this means url will grow long.Please help on this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you probably don't need long urls. In many cases you will just refer to the object(s) which a view should display or manipulate. Before allowing the user to do this, you check that the user has permission to access them. There are various ways to do this, but if the user profile has an organisation and the view object also has an organisation, you might define `get_object` for class-based views something like this:

```
def get_object( self, queryset=None):
    obj = super().get_object( self, queryset)

    if request.user.profile.organisation_id != obj.organisation_id:
        raise PermissionDenied('...') # or Http404 "not found"
    return obj
```

You need to do this *anyway* because a user can feed anything he wants to in though his browser's URL bar, for example to attempt to spy on some other organisation that he knows is sharing the system.

Some  might also want to use UUIDs as primary keys for sensitive entities, rather than sequentially increasing integers. (Doing so also makes URLs much longer!). The reason is  that successive integers are fairly guessable/ hackable, whereas UUIDs are not.

Comment: Ok so how to pass organization id from frontend api url . since user has accounts in multiple organisations..user as to follow any one organization flow..after selecting any particular organization

Comment: Don't understand your problem space enough to commen much. Was assuming a user was a member of one organisation, but you can create an organisation to user mapping that's ManyToMany and then check that objects accessed are within the user's organisations (plural).

Comment: ex.  user belongs to two organisation or projects  X1 and x2.so whenever user selects project X1 after login.. upcoming api calls should display/post data to X1 organisation only.so my question is where i have to store that initial selection of organisation/ project after login.if proceed with organisation id in url pathname also fine but it leads to long url
real world example: Netflix account with multiple users if we select anyone user and respective flow will be with that user only like previously watched movies for that particular user, upcoming suggestions etc

Comment: @mohammed_fayeez put the user's choice into the user's `request.session`, maybe? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/